# How to use tools directory in "data science at the command line" repo?

Tags: python, r, csv

I created a project to mimic the code in Jeroen Janssens' "Data Science at the Command Line". The GitHub repo is cloned to a local directory. (I didn't want to use the Vagrant-based setup and don't mind manual installation.)

The repo contains a tools directory, but it's unclear to me how to launch any of the tools from the command line. They include Drake, Rio, Scrape, Weka, among others.

I know I'm missing something very simple, but it's escaping me. Hints?

Comment: Look at the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of each file. For **Drake**, the shebang is *#!/bin/bash*. It's a shell script. For **Scrape**, it's *#!/usr/bin/env python2*, meaning it's a Python script. Other than that, look to the text or Google for individual usage of the programs.

Comment: And I had a bad PATH variable to boot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're in the same directory as the script (or command-line tool), you can execute it using `./my-script`. If you're not in the same directory, you can use the relative or absolute path. For instance, for `Rio`, you could run something like:

```
$ cd ~/data-science-at-the-command-line/book
$ cat ch05/data/iris.csv | ../tools/Rio -e 'mean(df$sepal_length)'
5.843333
```

If you intend to use a certain command-line tool more often, or would like to execute it from anywhere on your filesystem without specifying its path, it's helpful to put the directory that contains the command-line tool on the `PATH`. You can set this, for example, in `~/.bashrc` (assuming that Bash is your shell).